# Ghostscript: how to merge PDFs with wild card on Windows

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to merge all *.pdf in directory :

```
gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=Total_Files.pdf -dBATCH *.pdf
```

This is perfectly work for me on Linux, but when I run it on Windows
I'm getting `**Error: /undefinedfilename in *.pdf.**`.
Please could some one help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

(My problem was practically exactly the same). My solution (with the help of previous answers) answers the original question slightly better (an actual MS-DOS example is below)

```
del filename.lst
for %%s in (C:\somefolder\some?wildcards*.pdf) do ECHO %%s >> filename.lst
gswin64c.... @filename.lst
```

To explain;

'>>' means append in MS-DOS - so firstly we delete file filename.lst

I read (just now in some other place) that `%%s` in MS-DOS batch files works (instead of `%s`).  Obviously - one day the filenames may contain spaces (as mine did already) so better be safe and quote the filenames.  So the better batch file is;

```
del filename.lst
for %%s in (C:\somefolder\some?wildcards*.pdf) do ECHO "%%s" >> filename.lst
gswin64c.... @filename.lst
```

Right now I just used this for inputting many EPS files - but many PDF files work fine too; as in the above example - I actually tested it with both - my result is a PDF with many EPS files in it - and many pages from multiple PDF files in one PDF (as per the question).

Answer (score 2):

There was a previous question on this topic, the answer is the same, Ghostscript does not allow wildcards in the input filename, you must specify each file you want to have as input.

Why does it work on Linux ? Because the shell you are using expands '*.ps' to a full list of files *before* passing the command line to Ghostscript.

To do this in Windows you will need to execute a shell script, pipe the filenames to a file, then supply the file as an argument to GS.

EG, something like

```
for %s in (*.ps) do ECHO %s >> filename.lst
gswin64c.... @filename.lst
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've tried this solution and it works.

Comment: The only problem filename.lst coming unsorted. It sorts files name like varchar 1, 10, 11, 2, 20 etc.

Comment: You sir, are still a lifesaver in 2021. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the for loop

```
dir /b /o:n *.ps > filename.lst
```

gets the job done (/b to get the files only, /o:n to sort by name).

To solve the sorting problem completely, you could rename the first 9 files to 01->09, or open the output file in notepad and handle these few cases manually. But if you will have more than 100 files, this could be bothersome.

*Sorry to stir up this one year old thread, which helped me with my problem, but I thought using 'dir' is easier, more flexible and doesn't need you to delete the file list before starting.*